# python How to mute MNE warnings

Tags: python, mne-python, european-data-format

I'm using rapid loading of `.edf` files using the `mne` package. The problem is that the package is warning all the time and fills my screen with red warnings and it's disturbing my work.

How can I mute those warnings please?

**Warning Example:**

```
RuntimeWarning: Channel names are not unique, found duplicates for: {'T8-P8'}. Applying running numbers for duplicates.
  raw_data = mne.io.read_raw_edf(file_path, verbose=False)
```